# Convert a PDF to jpeg on the fly with ImageMagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, real-time

I'm trying to convert the first page of a PHP generated PDF to an image, and have done so with the following code:

```
exec("convert http://####.com/tcpdf/examples/example_009.php[0] -resize 100 sample.jpeg");
```

However I don't want to save the image, I'm looking for a way of including the command in a PHP script in place of an image, e.g: `<img src="display_image_script.php?pdf=dynamic_pdf.php">`

Is there a way to get ImageMagick to return the image within the PHP page using `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but try:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
passthru("convert somePdfFile.pdf jpeg:-");
```

You need the [passthru](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) to stream the binary back to the browser and the jpeg:- in the command string converts pdf to jpeg and returns the jpeg binary on stdout.

Comment: Hi Mark, first time I've ever heard of passthru, thanks for that! The code works perfectly as well! :)